# .htaccess file stop access of pic with direct URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website in php and CodeIgniter where user upload their profile pic and profile pic is stored in folder with name pic_uid.jpg .

And then my script load pic from same folder.

I want to stop direct access of pic using `.htaccess` file.

like if pic path is

```
http://localhost/myweb/uploads/users/pic_19.jpg
```

If some one type this direct path, he will not get access to pic but when my script call this pic he can get access and show the pic.

I have tried many options but when i stop access to directory, my script also can't load pic.

How to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Have a directory say, `secured`. And inside that directory, place this `.htaccess`:

```
Deny From All
```

And now, store all your image files there:

```
+ secured/
  - image-1.png
  - image-2.png
  - image-3.png
```

And in your PHP Script, use this proxy:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  /* true if the conditions met, like coming from the script or something */
  $right_user = true or false;
  if ($right_user) {
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    echo file_get_contents("secured/" . $_GET["file"]);
    die();
  } else {
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    die("Ha ha! Can't steal!");
  }
```

To reiterate what all I have done, I created a repo here at [Cloud9](https://demo-project-praveenscience.c9.io/php/). In that, I have got these files:

```
└── php
    ├── index.php
    ├── insecure.php
    └── secured
        ├── .htaccess
        └── hello.txt
```

And the each file has like this:

**`insecure.php`**

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    if (file_exists("secured/" . $_GET["file"]))
        echo file_get_contents("secured/" . $_GET["file"]);
    else
        echo "404! File Not Found.";
    die();
?>
```

**`secured/.htaccess`**

```
Deny From All
```

**`secured/hello.txt`**

```
Hello, World.
I am not accessible through normal requests.
My location is in /php/secured/hello.txt.
```

**Demos**

- Inaccessible Secure File: https://demo-project-praveenscience.c9.io/php/secured/hello.txt
- Accessible Secure File through PHP: https://demo-project-praveenscience.c9.io/php/insecure.php?file=hello.txt

> ***Note:*** I am on a free account, so the server runs only for some time. Please make use of it.

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not working, first when i use this code in my view file it only show vary tiny image and all page data is gone. also its not loading actual image too

Comment: @user3412718 What did you actually put as code? Can you show **your** code please?

Comment: i use exact same code you write, but in my view file of code igniter, there is two issues one when i put `header("Content-type: image/png");` all the output in view file is gone, second the file content is not reading properly and only blank image is coming... i check the path of file in `file_get_contents` and its correct path

Comment: @user3412718 `$right_user = true or false;` - This part should be changed. I said you.

Comment: yes i did't even use that part. i just want to see if it works then i will put that if command... this did't work without that part...

Comment: @user3412718 Yes, because `if ($right_user) {` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: @user3412718 See, you cannot access this directly: https://demo-project-praveenscience.c9.io/php/secured/hello.txt but can be accessed through: https://demo-project-praveenscience.c9.io/php/insecure.php?file=hello.txt

Comment: @user3412718 This works perfectly for me. You can see the source code too.

Comment: @user3412718 If this didn't work for you, sorry, I / any other devs cannot help you.

Comment: really thanks for all your efforts and i have wrote all mu code in chat you ask me... please see there my code and what i did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For stop access of pic with direct URL
Use URI of codeiginiter
copy this code in your routes.php

```
$route['uploads/users/(:any)'] = "page_not_found";
```

This code blocked all url accessing a folder **uploads/users**

Comment: did't work & how i will add all lines of url for every pic ?

Comment: sorry brother but i am not looking for URI routing, i am looking for stoping direct access to images

Comment: @user3412718 **URI routing** for redirect access to images to another page **page 404** for example